# Manipulating http request caused by updating img.src

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently creating a hybrid mobile app (see phonegap/cordova) for iOS and Android and noticed when updating the img.src url of an image (which I do frequently) that the Android http request looks like below.

My problem is that it doesn't include the all important Accept header (Accept: */*) so the server fails to load the image and returns (HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable). Chrome/iOS include this Accept header in their http requests when updating the img.src url.

My question is, is there a way to append this header or do *something* that would include this header for subsequent img.src updates?

**Android Http Request:**

```
GET /system/data/ba9320b8-e093-47a9-8858-c6343febf3ec/frame?t=1339017043002 HTTP/1.1
Host: MyHostName
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.2; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F)
AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
Cookie: auth_token=0882f24f-04d7-4f05-9475-cfe2a94af5bf
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a new image, instead of updating the src attribute of the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google implementation](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_net_imageloader.js.source.html#line173) to handle compatibility issues for all such problems. This is from inside the Closure Library, which is compatible with PhoneGap(at least so they say:)

Basically what you need to do is to alter the headers of the http request. A native xhr object has a method called setRequestHeader(param, value); which does what you are looking for. Use [remote debugging on Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging) to see what headers got sent and where.

I don't know what library you are using. The Google Closure Library let's you pass request headers as an object parameter to the send method of an xhr instance([SEE THIS](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_net_XhrIo.html)), so it's pretty easy. As far as I know, jQuery has a similar behavior as well.

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://someurl",
         data: { signature: authHeader },
         type: "GET",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');}
         success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
      });
```